# R - How to use dplyr left_join by column index?

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join

How to use column index to `dplyr::left_join` (and your family)?

Example (by column names):

```
    library(dplyr)
    data1 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b", "c"), var2 = c("d", "d", "f")) 
    data2 = data.frame(alpha = c("d", "f"), beta = c(20, 30))
    left_join(data1, data2, by = c("var2" = "alpha"))
```

However, replacing `by = c("var2" = "alpha"))` to `by = c(data1[,2] = data2[,1])` results to this error:

> `by` must be a (named) character vector, list, or NULL for natural
> joins (not recommended in production code), not logical.

I need to use the "column position" for loop on new functions.
How can I do it?

Comment: `left_join(data1, data2, by = c("var2" = "alpha"))`

Comment: You don't have `by = c("var2" == "alfa"))`, you have `by = c("var2" = "alfa"))`

Comment: Check your code: `alpha` or `alfa`?

Comment: I'm sorry. `by = c("var2" == "alpha"))` and "alfa" it's a syntax errors. I revised. This question is the column index use.

Comment: if you want to use column indexes, you can index the data frame names to specify the `by` parameter `colnames(data1)[1]`. Your attempt of `by = c(data1[,2] = data2[,1])` retrieves that column as a vector, not a single character string which is what the error message is referring to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
# rename_at changes alpha into var2 in data2
left_join(data1, rename_at(data2, 1, ~ names(data1)[2]), by = names(data1)[2])
# output
  var1 var2 beta
1    a    d   20
2    b    d   20
3    c    f   30
```

Using base `R`:

```
merge(data1, data2, by.x = 2, by.y = 1, all.x = T, all.y = F)
# output
  var2 var1 beta
1    d    a   20
2    d    b   20
3    f    c   30
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're going to use the column index but a hacky solution is the following:

```
#make a named vector for the by argument, see ?left_join
join_var <- names(data2)[1] #change index here based on data2
names(join_var) <- names(data1)[2] #change index here based on data1

left_join(data1, data2, by = join_var)
```

Depending on the final output you desire by using the column index, there is probably a more appropriate solution than this.